# Select the last date with ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT [CUSTOMER_ID], [PROPERTY_NAME], [LOCATION_CODE], [RESERVATION_DATE]    
FROM a
```

From the above table, I have to select each `property_Name` based on the last `RESERVATION_DATE`

```
[CUSTOMER_ID]  [PROPERTY_NAME]  [LOCATION_CODE]   [RESERVATION_DATE] 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   121          b                        B5              2019-12-19
   1256         c                        c5              2019-12-20
   1212         b                        B5              2019-12-22
   1236         a                        A5              2019-12-18
```

Output

```
[CUSTOMER_ID]  [PROPERTY_NAME]  [LOCATION_CODE]   [RESERVATION_DATE] 
-------------------------------------------------------------------   
 1212                b              B5               2019-12-22
 1256                c              c5               2019-12-20
 1236                a              A5               2019-12-18
```

Comment: which database are you using? (mysql, sqlite, postgres, oracle, sql-server....)

Comment: this SQL dialect looks like SQL Server dialect or MariaDB with sql_mode SQL Server enabled

Comment: add `ORDER BY [RESERVATION_DATE] DESC` to your SELECT statement.

Comment: SQL SERVER@RaymondNijland

Comment: when we add order by clause duplicates (121,1212) also displayed .i don't want that 
for each Property_Name lasted REservation Date I need @Luuk
display only 1212

Comment: PROPERTY_NAME should not be duplicated. it should display unique PROERTY_NAME @forpas

Comment: It is not duplicated (unless there are more than 1 rows with the latest date). Check the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT t.[CUSTOMER_ID], t.[PROPERTY_NAME], t.[LOCATION_CODE], t.[RESERVATION_DATE]  
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE [PROPERTY_NAME] = t.[PROPERTY_NAME] AND [RESERVATION_DATE] > t.[RESERVATION_DATE]
)
```

or with a subquery in the WHERE clause that returns the latest date:

```
SELECT t.[CUSTOMER_ID], t.[PROPERTY_NAME], t.[LOCATION_CODE], t.[RESERVATION_DATE]  
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE t.[RESERVATION_DATE] = (
  SELECT MAX([RESERVATION_DATE]) FROM tablename
  WHERE [PROPERTY_NAME] = t.[PROPERTY_NAME]
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f524a0eee7cb7db189ecbd758ad84787).
Results:

```
> CUSTOMER_ID | PROPERTY_NAME | LOCATION_CODE | RESERVATION_DATE   
> ----------: | :------------ | :------------ | :------------------
>        1256 | c             | c5            | 20/12/2019
>        1212 | b             | B5            | 22/12/2019
>        1236 | a             | A5            | 18/12/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `TOP WITH TIES` here along with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES CUSTOMER_ID, PROPERTY_NAME, LOCATION_CODE, RESERVATION_DATE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROPERTY_NAME, LOCATION_CODE
                            ORDER BY RESERVATION_DATE DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have various ways to achieve this:

Using the a windowing function:

```
    SELECT t.[CUSTOMER_ID],
           t.[PROPERTY_NAME],
           t.[LOCATION_CODE],
           t.[RESERVATION_DATE]
    FROM   (
           SELECT [CUSTOMER_ID],
                  [PROPERTY_NAME],
                  [LOCATION_CODE],
                  [RESERVATION_DATE],
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                      PARTITION BY [PROPERTY_NAME],
                      [LOCATION_CODE] 
                      ORDER BY [RESERVATION_DATE] DESC
                  ) rn
           FROM   a
       ) t
    WHERE  rn = 1
    ORDER BY
           t.RESERVATION_DATE DESC
```

Using the `GROUP BY`:

```
     SELECT MAX(CUSTOMER_ID)       AS CUSTOMER_ID,
           [PROPERTY_NAME],
           [LOCATION_CODE],
           MAX(RESERVATION_DATE)  AS RESERVATION_DATE
    FROM   a
    GROUP BY
           [PROPERTY_NAME],
           [LOCATION_CODE]
    ORDER BY
           RESERVATION_DATE          DESC
```